# How to ensure child background processes terminate when using `set -e`?

Tags: bash, job-control

```
set -e

while true; do echo "test"; sleep 1; done &

echo "done"
ueoa
```

If I run this, once it reaches `ueoa` (a random command that does not exist), it'll 'terminate' but keep the `while true; do echo "test"; sleep 1; done` running.

How can I ensure the foreground process gets terminated as well in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' ERR

set -e

while true; do echo "test"; sleep 1; done &

echo "done"
ueoa
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
function cleanup()
{
    kill $!
}
trap cleanup ERR
while true; do echo "test"; sleep 1; done &
echo "done"
ueoa
```

Comment: Although it would in this particular case it's not very reliable and future proof - it's enough to start a new background process just after `while true; do echo "test"; sleep 1; done &` and it never gets killed.